# Run dialog execute powershell command

Tags: windows, powershell

Is there a way to run a powershell command when opening the run box (Windows+R)?

I'd like to just start typing get-process for example and have it execute that command in powershell and display the result (basically opening it and not closing it).

I know you can type "powershell /noexit get-process" to achieve this, but I'd like to know if there's a way the Run box realizes it's a powershell command and all I have to type is the command: get-process.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**No**, there is no way to make <kbd>Windows</kbd>+<kbd>R</kbd> understand PowerShell commands directly.

One workaround is to create a batch file with content like this:

```
@echo off
%systemroot%\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\powershell.exe -noexit -noprofile -noLogo "%1 %2 %3 %4 %5 %6 %7 %8"
```

name it `p.cmd` and put it in a location that is in your path.

Now you can do:

[image: Run example]

start with `p` then the PowerShell command you want to execute.

Comment: Yes, `Powershell.exe` is in the path, but using the fully qualified path to it means Windows doesn't have to look through all the locations in the `%path%` to find it. It may only save a few milliseconds, but that's the way I do it. Plus what if someone adds a different `powershell.exe` to a location that is first listed in `%path%` This can be a security issue.

Comment: A tiny improvement: use %* instead of %1 %2 %3... that will allow you to pass as many arguments as you want.

Answer (score 5):

Might be a bit too late, but you are able to run CMD commands through the run box, and then again PowerShell commands through CMD. By utilizing this you can type:

```
cmd /k PowerShell.exe "Your PowerShell command"
```

where the `/k` can be changed wirh `/c` if you don't want the CMD-window to stay open.
[In the end it could look something like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NtkSD.png)